# How to set testNG to ignore priority annotations of other classes inside the same test suite while running them in parallel?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, annotations, browser-automation, testng-eclipse

At the moment I am getting that e.g. Test with priority = 1 in Class A has finished and is now waiting for Test with priority = 1 in Class B to finish before continuing which is a time waster.

All I want is my classes to run in parallel but to respect priority only inside themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the same in your `testng.xml` file:-

For parallel class you can use:-

```
<suite name="My suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">
```

You will be mentioning your priority of test cases in your class. It will work then.

Answer (score 0):

TestNg provide such fetaur for more details go through [Testng](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running)